# How to extract 2 properties from an array of objects as an observabe?

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have an observable of an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "New York",
    latitude: 15.5539737,
    longitude: -78.5989487
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Chicago",
    latitude: 55.5539737,
    longitude: 28.5989487
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Los Angeles",
    latitude: 95.5539737,
    longitude: -72.587
  }
]
```

How can I return a new observable array of objects that extracts only 2 of the properties (latitude and longitude)?

Comment: The array contains only 3 objects or variable number of objects?

Comment: Variable. I kept the example array concise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use map operator from RxJS first, then use map from Array, as follows:

```
// first use the map operator from RxJS    
    YourObservable.map(x=>{
    // then use Array.prototype.map
        x.map(return {longiture:x.longitude, latitude:x.latitude})
        })
```

Do not confuse the two maps used above, [one](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) is from RxJS and the [other](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is from Array, both are completely different.

Also note that if you use RxJS6, you need to use pipe as follows:

```
 YourObservable.pipe(
     map(x=>{
           x.map(return {longiture:x.longitude, latitude:x.latitude})
        }))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "New York",
    latitude: 15.5539737,
    longitude: -78.5989487
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Chicago",
    latitude: 55.5539737,
    longitude: 28.5989487
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Los Angeles",
    latitude: 95.5539737,
    longitude: -72.587
  }
]

const example2= from(arr).pipe(map(a => {
  return {latitude: a.latitude, longitude: a.longitude,}
}));
const subscribe = example2.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```